# Review of: voltmeter, ampmeter, ohmmeter circuits for Arduino

Tags: amplifier, adc, multimeter

I'd like to build a multimeter with an Arduino Due. Could you review the following circuits and tell me what I should improve?

---

### Voltmeter

Requirements:

- Ranges: -30V -> 30V, split into a) -30->30V b) -12->12V c) -6->6V c) -3->3V and another set without the negative voltages to double the accuracy
- Accuracy: 1% of voltage range, e.g. 0.3V max on highest range (see above)
- Bandwidth: 400kHz

Circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwq4OL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Ampmeter

Requirements:

- Ranges: -5A->5A, split into a) -5->5A b) -1A->1A c) -200mA->200mA and another set without the negative currents to double the accuracy
- Accuracy: 1% of current range, e.g. 50mA max on highest range (see above)
- Bandwidth: 100kHz

Circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVb223.png)</sup>

### Ohmmeter

Requirements:

- Ranges: a) 0->1k b) 1k->10k c) 10k->100k d) 100k->1M
- Accuracy: 1% of resistance range, e.g. 10k on highest range (see above)

Circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJdANB.png)</sup>

---

All resistors are 0.1%, calibration will be done via offsets in software. Any suggestions on different circuits, different parts...? I'd like to keep the cost low, like ~15$ for 6 voltmeters, 3 ampmeters and 1 ohmmeter circuits. Apparently the ACS712 is ~1.6$ on ebay.

Comment: This should be posted as 3 separate questions. For example, so it's easier to pick an accepted answer if some answers are good on one circuit but bad on another.

Comment: It's Ammeter, not Amp meter. And @thephoton I disagree, we don't always require schematic questions to be broken down to individual modules. This is just three parts to the same multimeter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm only doing the voltmeter circuit: -

The LM833 is a rubbish choice - its output voltage capability on a +/- 15V supply is only guaranteed to be +/-12V - this means that on a 3V3 supply you get sweet F.A. out of it. It's not a single rail op-amp: -

[image]

Basically it won't work on a supply below +/- 5V.

Neither does it have a power bandwidth of 400 kHz - PB is 120 kHz.

Another problem with the op-amp is the input offset currents may be as high as 200nA - given that you have 1Mohm resistors attenuating the signal and the potential to be feeding the input signal in via 9M1 resistors, the impedance seen by this current is 900kohm. With 200nA flowing you'll have an error voltage of 180mV added to your signal and eating into your error budget significantly.

Input offset voltage is 5 mV and on your low voltage setting (gain of 10) this becomes 50mV on the output. Given that your error budget for this range is 30mV you've blown it!!

I think you should be considering an instrumentation amplifier run from a +/- 5V supply, maybe the AD8221.

It looks like you are misusing the LM833 on the other sections of the question so you get those parts reviewed on that bad choice for free!

I suggest you concentrate on getting one bit right, learn from your mistakes and apply the "learnings" to the next section of the design. In other words reduce this question to the voltmeter part and once you are happy with it being OK ask another question.

Comment: Never been so happy to be criticised so heavily :) Thanks a lot. I didn't give a lot of thought in the choice of amplifier just yet and focussed on the circuit instead, but I can see how it's in fact the most important. Instrumentation amplifiers actually do most of my circuit, in fact... The AD8221 is perfect except for the cost. It's WAY too expensive. The cheapest of all I.A. on Farnell is just about right, the MCP6N16-100E/MS - looks good, although it's single supply. What do you think? Then, I'll update my schematics.

Comment: The MCP6N16-100E/MS is very noisy (like about 100x noisier than the AD8221) but should work on your 3V3 rail but only down to a couple of millivolts on the output on a light load. Update your schematics but post as a new question so that nobody gets confused when reading my answers in a week or a year. Many folk will (hopefully) benefit from this Q and A as it stands and that (I believe) is important to stack exchange. Money = quality!

Comment: Right, I hadn't seen that... THanks! I have browsed Farnell for hours and I think I've found a good compromise: http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/ina826aidgkr/ic-instr-amp-1mhz-130bd-vssop/dp/2064255; no need for diodes, too. I'll provide the -5V with http://uk.farnell.com/intersil/icl7660cbaz/volt-converter-smd-7660-soic8/dp/9663703. I want to switch between volt/current/ohm on the same opamp, I'll think of a circuit and post a new question.

Comment: OK I'll look out for the new question

Comment: The new question is here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/200326/multimeter-circuit-review. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please feel free to mark this answer as "accepted" - hit the little "tick" circle below the upvote/downvote arrows at the top left of my answer.

Comment: Of course, silly me!

Comment: LOL = by the way your circuit diagram in your new question is impossible to read values and parts.

Comment: Yes I know, it's a problem with the circuit editor online. The only way I've found to see the values is "Edit" post > "Edit this schematic"... Sorry for the hassle, I just want the circuit to be on one sheet as an overview

Comment: You could save a screen capture (which has OK resolution) then frig around in paint to save as a jpg then post it back or, just cramp up the components a bit more.

Comment: Good idea, done.