# Multimeter circuit review

Tags: amplifier, analog, instrumentation-amplifier

I'm designing a very simple multimeter circuit of which the ADC is that of an Arduino Due. Could you have a look at the circuit and tell me what could go wrong, what could be improved etc.?

### Requirements

- Voltmeter mode: ranges 30V, 10V, 3V, 1V OR +/-15V, +/-5V, +/-1.5V, +/-0.5V; bandwidth >= 300kHz
- Ammeter mode: ranges 5A, 1A, 0.2A OR +/-2.5A, +/-0.5A, +/-0.1A; bandwidth >= 100kHz
- Ohmmeter mode: ranges 1k, 10k, 100k, 1M

The accuracy required is 1% of selected range in all modes.

### Circuit

CircuitLab editable:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQiWij.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Full res picture:[image]

The circuit is illustrated in voltmeter mode on the 10V range, here is the jumper position map for the 3 modes, the ranges, and the +/- switch. Each cell is a 2 pin header (except the +/- switch which is a 3 pin header) and contains the reference of the corresponding switch on the schematic. Physically, there is a 2x2 pin jumper, and a 2 pin jumper moved left or right, and a 2 pin jumper moved up or down.

[image]

The reason for the > 3V range is that the instrumentation amplifier does not allow gains lower than unity, therefore there is a divide by 10 stage with 10M input impedance inserted before the amplifier. The amplifier is internally protected up to +/-40V. Note that selecting a +/- range halves the range.

Comment: "Note that selecting a +/- range halves the [...] accuracy." Then you've written your software incorrectly.

Comment: Biggest problem I see is lack of input protection. If you're measuring 3 volts and accidentally put your probes across line voltage, what will happen? Likewise with current measurements - what happens if you touch a robust voltage source (worst case: line voltage)?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: thanks for your suggestion. As I mention in the text, the INA826 is internally protected up to +/-40V. I'll clearly state the maximum voltage on the PCB, if a higher voltage is applied accidentally the opamp will burn out. I'm not sure if it will take out anything else down the line. The current measurement is safe (at least up to 40V), the current line is isolated via the hall effect sensor and voltages are clamped. Not sure what happens when 40V is applied in ohmmeter mode either, that's 36mA max in the regulator.

Comment: I recommend you watch the eevblog Video about multimeter input protection

Comment: @PlasmaHH: That's good advice, though what Dave shows is the protection of a CATIV device, I don't need this level of protection as my unit is not meant to be used above 30V (I'd like to keep it safe but cheap). Not sure what I can/should use though to make it safe. Fuses on the Ammeter are obvious, no idea for the voltmeter side.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

- The [ACS712](http://www.allegromicro.com/~/Media/Files/Datasheets/ACS712-Datasheet.ashx) current transformer you're using has a max bandwidth of 80kHz, below your desired target of 100kHz.
- The ACS712 also has a listed total output error of +/-1.5% at a nominal 25 degrees C; temperature changes makes this worse. If the noise is low enough and you have the equipment to measure the error you might be able account for this in software to get better than 1% accuracy, but I wouldn't expect it to just work.
- Same goes for the DUE's ADC accuracy: The SAM3x MCU it uses is specified at +.29%/-1.56%, presumably using the internal reference? It's within a 2% range corresponding to +/-1%, but it's shifted down a bit (again, this could be software calibrated out if you can measure the error).
- Even if you have no intention of adding full over-voltage protection present in standard multimeters, I would still add series resistors to the inputs of the INA826 to take advantage of the internal overvoltage protection of the opamp *Because Dumb Stuff Happens*™ (see [Fig. 58](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina826.pdf))
- You might need better bypassing caps, say a 1uF, 100nF, 10nF parallel combo. If you're building a custom PCB I would at least add extra pads for these, then populate them as needed.

Comment: Thanks, those are very good comments. 1) I'm planning on reducing the filter cap to 680pF to increase the ACS bandwidth 2) That's my main concern. The slightest offset from 2.5V will get amplified up to 80 times on the 0.2A range. I'll add a trimmer on the volt. divider 3) I found this very nice page on the Due's ADC and apparently I can get a fairly good performance out of it. http://www.djerickson.com/arduino/ 4) I can't add series resistors without loading the divide by 10 stage, can I? 5) Good point, where in particular? 6) Other than that, is it going to work okay?

Comment: Just noticed that the MAX bandwidth of the ACS was 80kHz. Close enough, though the accuracy drops to 400mA because of the noise level generated by the IC. I tried to find a better current sensor but it seems to be the best compromise around. Looks like that's as good as cheap ammeters get doesn't it!

Comment: 4) Yes, you can. See the figure I referenced from the datasheet. The op-amp input terminals are "infinite impedance" normally, so a small resistance in series with this is still "infinite" and has no effect.
5) I would at least add them for the hall sensor and op-amp.
6) It's not the design I would use, and I doubt it will meet you original specifications for the reasons I mentioned. That doesn't mean it won't work at all, just not as intended. If the actual performance it gives you is good enough, maybe the correct answer is you had the wrong specs to begin with.

Comment: Thanks. "it's not the design I would use" Do you already have an idea of what you would do instead? I'd like to meet those specs.

Comment: I would use a shunt resistor for current measurements, possibly in a ladder configuration with switches to select different shunt values. You already have an in-amp so you should be able to use it to reduce the burden voltage. The added benefit is bandwidth is now primarily limited by the op-amp, and it's relatively easy to find high-precision shunts.

Answer (score 1):

I think to do the job justice you should adopt a self-protecting voltmeter input like this one: -

[image]

I extracted this picture from a dodgy site that tried to download an exe but I stopped it and tamed it. The words alongside the circuit were these: -

> In contrast to an ordinary voltmeter, the input of an oscilloscope
>   generally has one side (GND) connected to ground via the mains lead.
>   In certain situations this can be very problematic. When the measuring
>   probe is connected to a circuit that is also connected to ground,
>   there is a chance that a short is introduced in the circuit. That the
>   circuit, and hence the measurement, is affected by this is the least
>   of your problems. If you were taking measurements from high current or
>   high voltage (valve equipment) circuits, the out-come could be
>   extremely dangerous! Fortunately it is not too difficult to get round
>   this problem. All you have to do is make the input to the oscilloscope
>   float with respect to ground. The instrumentation amplifier shown here
>   does that, and functions as an attenuator as well. The AD621 from
>   Analog Devices amplifies the input by a factor of 10, and a switch at
>   the input gives a choice of 3 ranges. A GND position has also been
>   included, to calibrate the zero setting of the oscilloscope. The
>   maximum input voltage at any setting may never exceed 600 VAC. Make
>   sure that R1 and R8 have a working voltage of at least 600 V. You
>   could use two equal resistors connected in series for these, since 300
>   V types are more easily obtainable. You should also make sure that all
>   resistors have a tolerance of 1% or better. Other specifications for
>   the AD621 are: with an amplification of 10 times the CMRR is 110 dB
>   and the bandwidth is 800 kHz. If you can`t find the AD621 locally, the
>   AD620 is a good alternative. However, the bandwidth is then limited to
>   about 120 kHz. The circuit can be housed inside a metal case with a
>   mains supply, but also works perfectly well when powered from two 9V
>   batteries. The current consumption is only a few milliamps. You could
>   also increase R9 to 10 k to reduce the power consumption a bit more.

You are using a R2R instrumentation op-amp on a much smaller supply but that's the only real difference. Note the 4 protection diodes and also note the symmetry of the inputs. Concentrate on getting the voltmeter right then figure out getting the current side going - you could even feed the current signal into the MCU seperately - it doesn't need to use the same mechanisms as the voltmeter for controlling range.

Comment: I like that scheme, thanks. That topology works for the same sort of 2x2 jumpers. I just don't know how to include the ohmmeter feature in this circuit for resistances up to 1M with 1% accuracy.. Is it that bad to use the original circuit?

Comment: @user42875 - I think this is a staged question, work out how you want the voltmeter then ask another question about taking it to include an ohm meter. You should get a few good ideas and it may be better to leave the basic volt meter functionality as it is or use the voltmeter to measure the voltage thru a resistor driven with an accurate current source. You could use some kind of switch arrangement to disentangle the intrumentation amp from its resistors to get an accurate measurement of volts across a 1MΩ.

Comment: The thing is, the voltmeter and the ohmmeter are not two separate problems: I can't choose a voltmeter topology without thinking of how it's going to work with the ohmmeter. In this example, I've realised your R ladder was necessary to measure any voltage with potentials >= 5V on IN-; however that GND in the middle bothers me to the point I don't know how to set up my current source - even if it's a simple pull-up. Two options then: remove the R ladder in ohmmeter mode, or use separate inputs for the ohmmeter (necessary?); in both cases there is no input protection! Am I missing anything?